# Literal types in mocked json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, types

So I have this JSON:

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "abstract"
    },
    {
      "type": "machine"
    },
    {
      "type": "user"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here are my types:

```
export type StateStructure = {
  type: 'user' | 'machine' | 'abstract';
};
```

But when I try to import the JSON as data and set it to this type, like so:

```
export const constructStatesTreeStructure = (
  data: StatesRootData = states,
) => ...
```

I get this error:

```
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"abstract" | "user" | "machine"'.
```

Which makes sense. TS doesn't know, that all values in JSON `type` field, are actually one of these 3. But how can I "cast" it, or "tell" TS, that these are the only 3 values possible in this JSON?

I tried doing smth like

`type: string & ('user' | 'machine' | 'abstract')`

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this solved it:

```
export const constructStatesTreeStructure = (
  data: StatesRootData = states as StatesRootData,
) => ...
```